# Center two-lined Button Title

Tags: ios, uibutton, interface-builder, text-alignment

I want my button title to be centered and simply selected word-wrap in the Attributes Inspector to have two lines.

But the second line is not displayed centered but starts at the same position as the first line (the first line is longer).

How can I center both lines? (I'm using Swift.)

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Interface Builder, or programmatically?

Comment: If it can be done in Interface Builder then this way

Comment: Whoops, ignore my answer--was thinking label.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot set the text alignment of UIButton in interface builder. Create and connect an IBOutlet for the said button in interface builder, and use the following code in viewDidLoad method of the view controller.

```
ibOutletOfButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
```

I hope it helps!:-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try it I get the error: "UILabel? does not have a member named 'textAlignment'".

Comment: @maidi, That is weird because UILabel has a property called textAlignment. Please see the link below; https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textAlignment

Comment: I tried again and it worked now, I had to type a '?' after 'titleLabel', thanks :)

Comment: Sorry about the '?', I'm not familiar with swift. Anyway, glad it helped. :-)